# Accessing Russian App store

Tags: ipad, games

My mother is Russian, she lives with me but does not speak a word of English. I'm considering buying her an iPad for her birthday, but I have concerns since Russian apps would be hard to find in US app store. Is there a way I could access the Russian app store?

I tried a few online app search websites but as it is now, most of the games she would be interested in come in multiple languages and as soon as I open them in iTunes they switch to English.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To use the Russian App Store you need to create an account there using whatever payment method is available. Apple matches credit cards to country so you'll need a card issued in Russia to buy any apps
- Multi-lingual apps use the language configured on the phone. So even if you buy an app in the US store it will switch to Russian if running on such an iPhone (at least as long as the developers translated it to Russian in the first place)

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful! I did not know apps switch language to match phone. If that's the case, then I don't think I have any issues.